# how do I display text with a colored background when I select one of the contents of the combo box in php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have 3 text in combobox (primary,danger,warning) when i clicked the one of that, text will be displayed based on the combobox selected with the background color, the example, i select danger text in combobox that will displayed text danger with the red background, how i to make it in php, javascript?

https://prnt.sc/qfqx2v
https://prnt.sc/qfqx86

i have example just click the link on top

Answer (score 0):

In your css you can do something like this :

(if you use radio buttons):

```
.input[type="radio"]:checked {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

(if you use dropdown):

```
option:checked {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this using plain `javascript`.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jrh068xk/3/)

I put comments in the code for explanation.

```js
// Select the dropdown color selector.

var colorSelect = document.querySelector("#colors");


// Add a function to run, each time a new option(color) is selected.'

colorSelect.addEventListener("change", changeColor);


// Run the function from the previous event listener.
// The function get the color with "this.value", where this is the selected value. 
// This works since each option has a value in the markup, otherwise you had to get the text value.
// Then it sets the background color of the body to the selected color.

function changeColor() {
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = selectedValue;
}
```

```html
<select name="colors" id="colors">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
</select>
```

---

**Updated answer**

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j3ycu06f/4/)

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");
var colorSelect = document.querySelector("#colors");

colorSelect.addEventListener("change", changeColor);

function changeColor() {
  var selectedColor = this.value;
  var selectedType = colorSelect.options[colorSelect.selectedIndex].text;

  box.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
  box.innerHTML = selectedType;
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<select name="colors" id="colors">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="red">Danger</option>
  <option value="yellow">Warning</option>
  <option value="green">Success</option>
</select>
```

Comment: sorry , i mean like this https://prnt.sc/qfqx2v click this link thanks

Comment: I updated my answer, hopefully this is what you are looking for. @AgamPramana

Answer (score 0):

As you said **combobox** you can use **wijmo** library and code (full-screen to test snippets) and [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/maxofpower/Ld7y041x/8/)

```js
onload = function() {

  // create some random data
  var names = 'primary,warning,danger'.split(','),
    data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    data.push({
      name: names[i]
    });
  }

  var theComboString = new wijmo.input.ComboBox('#theComboString', {
    selectedIndexChanged: function(s, e) {
     setText('theComboStringCurrent', s.text);
    },
    itemsSource: names
 });
 

 // show text in an element on the page
  function setText(id, value) {
   document.getElementById(id).textContent = value;
    if(value=="primary")
    {
    $("#theComboString").css("background-color","green");
    }
    if(value=="danger")
    {
    $("#theComboString").css("background-color","red");
    }
     if(value=="warning")
    {
    $("#theComboString").css("background-color","orange");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.grapecity.com/wijmo/5.latest/styles/wijmo.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.grapecity.com/wijmo/5.latest/controls/wijmo.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.grapecity.com/wijmo/5.latest/controls/wijmo.input.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">

  <h1>
    ComboBox
  </h1>

  <label for="theComboString">Strings:</label>
  <div id="theComboString"></div>
  <p>
    The current value is: <b id="theComboStringCurrent"></b>.
  </p>

</div>
```